# Angular detected that `HttpClient` is not configured to use `fetch` APIs. (Angular 17 - SSR)

Tags: angular, httpclient, fetch-api, server-side-rendering

I got this error after updating to angular 17:

> NG02801: Angular detected that `HttpClient` is not configured to use `fetch` APIs. It's strongly recommended to enable `fetch` for applications that use Server-Side Rendering for better performance and compatibility. To enable `fetch`, add the `withFetch()` to the `provideHttpClient()` call at the root of the application.

I think after coding my services and importing `HttpClient` via inject functions it reached to this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`NG02801` is not an error but an warning that encourage the developers to enable the fetch implementation of the `HttpClient`.

To do this, just call `provideHttpClient(withFetch())` in your `app.config.ts`.

Comment: does this mean we can remote HttpClientModule? and provide it with that instead?

Comment: Use `HttpClientModule` when you bootstrap an AppModule and  `provideHttpClient` when you bootstrap an `AppComponent` !

Comment: Is there any document to reference this setup? Couldn’t find same behavior from http client module

Comment: What are you looking for exactly ? It should be used with the helpers mentionned here : https://angular.io/api/common/http/provideHttpClient

Comment: is HttpClientModule using fetch API as well?

Comment: No it doesn't. Fetch is only available with `provideHttpClient`.

Comment: You can also use provideHttpClient when using an AppModule, this not limited to AppComponent-Bootstraping

Comment: Could someone share a complete example for this? My angular CLI did not get generate a new project with a app.config.ts file. (noob problem).

Comment: I found and example file here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/aio/content/examples/dependency-injection/src/app/app.config.ts

Answer (score 9):

use this

```
import { provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withFetch()), provideRouter(routes), provideClientHydration()]
};
```